# snowflake enforce unsorted json into variant column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to insert value in a json column. and then python is reading the key from the column and creating a csv header. I need to maintain the column sequence However after loading into snowflake it seems the key is getting sorted into alphabetical order. is there a way I can enforce the order in snowflake.

Till now, this is what I have tried.

```
create table xyz_table(id int,json_column variant ); 
insert into xyz_table(id, json_column) select 1, parse_json($${
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Corner",
  "createddate": "2019-07-02T10:01:30+00:00",
  "type": "Owner",
  "country": {
    "code": "US",
    "name": "United States"
  }
}$$);
```

On selecting the table, the value of json_column is getting sorted by itself.
Please suggest

Comment: The rows in a table have no intrinsic order. If you want to select them in a specific order then you have to use an ORDER BY clause - if that’s what you are asking?

Comment: @NickW No Thats not what I need. The key of json column in the table is automatically getting sorted by snowflake. and not in the sequence they way we are putting it to. I need to maintain the key in the same order as put in the json_column.

Comment: Ok, then please update your question with a) the sql you are running b) the result that this is giving you and c) the result that you want to achieve